# How to see where the user installed my app from

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, ads

How my app was installed, how to track where the downloads are coming from, through which partner (advertising publisher)?

For example, I created ads in Facebook or in AdMob. User saw the ads, clicked on them, was redirected to the Google Play Store where he downloaded my app. How can I know that this user downloaded my app by clicking on the Facebook or AdMob ads? Does Google Analytics track and show this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily set up install tracking for Mobile Apps:

1. Enable app install tracking in your account.

Install tracking is automatically enabled in Google Analytics for Android apps. You don’t have to do anything!

2. Update your Google Analytics SDK.

You need to change a few lines in their manifest file. Refer to the [Developer Guide for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) for specific example on how to do this.

3. Set up Custom Campaigns.

Custom Campaigns are a Google Analytics feature that add parameters to the URL of your marketplace page where users download your app. It’s these parameters that tell Google Analytics what marketplaces your traffic comes from. Get an overview of Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics and how they work. You must set up Custom Campaigns for each platform you’re using.

4. Analyze your data using the Mobile App Sources report.

If you complete the steps outlined above, your data will appear in the Mobile App Sources report. Use this report to find out what brings users to your download page in each marketplace.

Reference: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142